# Manipulate SQL values before displaying on GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

***N,V,C,D*** are the variables in a bound column of my GridView.

When I display this table in my GridView, I want ***New,Verified,Cancelled,Deleted*** to be displayed instead.

My GridView calls a procedure in my database that runs the select Query. Do I need to change the query or add a GridView function? I do not want to change my database values per se.

How do I go about this?

This is my bound field as of now:

```
<asp:BoundField 
    DataField="Status"
    HeaderText="Status"
    SortExpression="Status" />
```

Comment: [SQL - Alias](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm)??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I do not want to change my column headers. I want to replace the data it retrieves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I edited the **status** column of the GridViewControl from the default *BoundField* and changed it to *ItemTemplate*

(I removed the autogenerated *EditItemTemplate* tag)

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblStatus"  
                 runat="server" 
                 Text='<%# GetLabelText(Eval("status")) %>'>
 </asp:Label>
```

Then in my CS file, I added the following code:

```
public string GetLabelText(object dataItem)
    {
    string text = "";
    string val = dataItem as string;
    switch (val)
        {
        case "N":   text = "New"; 
             break;
        case "V":   text = "Verified";
            break;
        case "F":   text = "Fulfilled";
            break;
        case "C":   text = "Cancelled";
            break;
        }
    return text;
    }
```

This worked like a charm. Thanks for the help, guys!

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible in C# - at least if you only wan to display the values and not edit them. In the CellFormatting event you can simply change the value to be displayed.

```
private void gridview_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Value.equals("N")) e.Value = "New";
  else if(e.Value.equals("V")) e.Value = "Verified";
  else if(e.Value.equals("C")) e.Value = "Cancelled";
  else if(e.Value.equals("D")) e.Value = "Deleted";
}
```

I haven't got C# at hand right now, so there may be typos. Just try it.

Comment: Where do I call this event?

Comment: You don't call events. Events happen. You write a method to react on an event associated with a control. Is there no CellFormatting event for your gridview? What gridview do you use? A DataGridView?

Comment: I just use a gridview.`<asp:GridView ID="Gv_IndentsForIp" runat="server"`

Comment: Ah, okay. It seems, for ASP GridView you'd use the RowDataBound event. I have no experience with that. I hope Sajeetharan's answer will help you.

Comment: I use a bound field and those don't seem to have ID tags. That's why I'm having some problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

In your query,

```
Select 
      YourFields
      case 
      when YourConditionField= 'N' then 'New' 
      when YourConditionField= 'V' then 'Verified'
      when YourConditionField= 'C' then 'Cancelled'
      when YourConditionField= 'D' then 'Deleted'
      end,
from table
```

First in GridView,

You can use the RowDataBound event, You need to add a template column with a label to your grid view

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="labelResult" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       string value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
       Next find the label in the template field.
        Label myLabel = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("myLabel");
        if (value == "N")
        {
            myLabel.Text = "New";
        }
        else if (value == "V")
        {
            myLabel.Text = "Verified";
        }
        else if (value == "C")
        {
            myLabel.Text = "Cancelled";
        }
        else if (value == "D")
        {
            myLabel.Text = "Deleted";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use bound fields, not template fields. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NEW" DataField="N" ></asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: yes, You can add bound fields as many as you need and keep header text as a column name as you like. and DataField as your column name coming output from DB.